# How to write properly to STM32f411 flash using arduino

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-c++

I have this question because I was standing still and I don't know what to do;)
I would like to write to Flash stm32 using arduino library latitude and longitude of 3 European capitals;)
I am a layman when it comes to programming. Below is my code.
Could someone please help me how to properly write these values in flash. Then I would like to read them, but first I want to focus on writing to flash.

I use this library
https://github.com/khoih-prog/FlashStorage_STM32

```js
        #include <FlashStorage_STM32.h>
        
        const int WRITTEN_SIGNATURE = 0xBEEFDEED;
        
        // Create a structure that is big enough to contain a latitude
        // and a longitude. The "valid" variable is set to "true" once
        // the structure is filled with actual data for the first time.
        typedef struct
        {
          int index[3];
          char latitude[100];
          char longitude[100];
        } Capitals;
        //data
        int data11 = 52,211233;
        int data12 = 4,532122;
        int data21 = 38,024321; 
        int data22 = 23,443456;
        int data31 = 38,024321; 
        int data32 = 23,443456;
        
        void setup()
        {
          Serial.begin(115200);
          while (!Serial);
        
          delay(200);
        
          Serial.print(F("\nStart StorelatitudeAndlongitude on ")); Serial.println(BOARD_NAME);
          Serial.println(FLASH_STORAGE_STM32_VERSION);
        
          Serial.print("EEPROM length: ");
          Serial.println(EEPROM.length());
        
          // Check signature at address 0
          int signature;
        
          // Create a "Capitals" variable and call it "owner"
          uint16_t storedAddress = 0;
          Capitals owner;
        
          EEPROM.get(storedAddress, signature);
        
          
            Serial.println("EEPROM is empty, writing WRITTEN_SIGNATURE and some example data:");
        
            EEPROM.put(storedAddress, WRITTEN_SIGNATURE);
        
            // ...in this case we ask for user data.
            Serial.setTimeout(30000);
            Serial.print("Insert your latitude : ");
            String latitude = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
            Serial.println(latitude);
            Serial.print("Insert your longitude : ");
            String longitude = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
            Serial.println(longitude);
        
            // Fill the "owner" structure with the data entered by the user...
            latitude.toCharArray(owner.latitude, 100);
            longitude.toCharArray(owner.longitude, 100);
        
            // ...and finally save everything into emulated-EEPROM
            EEPROM.put(storedAddress + sizeof(signature), owner);
        
            // Print a confirmation of the data inserted.
            Serial.print("<< Your latitude: "); Serial.print(owner.latitude);
            Serial.print(". Your longitude: "); Serial.print(owner.longitude);
            Serial.println(" >> have been saved. Thank you!");
          }
        
        
        void loop()
        {
          // Do nothing...
        }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: it looks good. what is the problem?